# Query working in phpMyAdmin but not in MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

I got this code:

```
$qstring = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count,name FROM schedules WHERE position = 'test' GROUP BY name ORDER BY count DESC";
        if ($result = $mysqli->prepare($qstring)) {

            /* execute query */
            $result->execute();

            /* bind result variables */
            $result->bind_result($count,$name);
            /* fetch value */
            $result->fetch();

            printf($count, $name);

            /* close statement */
            $result->close();
        }
```

The query above works when ran through phpMyAdmin but it doesn't return anything (nor throwing any errors) when run using the code above. I've tried using non prepared statements as well but I get the same empty results. All functions are returning true so no errors are occuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Joe Rose's reply, I made the modification he suggested but this wasn't enough.

I had a double issue with my initial code. The main problem was the php file encoding. Since I was using hardcoded strings for testing purposes, I forgot to change the file encoding to UTF-8 and since I'm using Swedish special characters in my strings, It was causing an unhandled crash thus the empty results. Changing the encoding and re-saving the php file solved the issue.

Also my code above won't return the expected results. Here is my final code that is working correctly and is returning the expected results:

```
$qstring = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count,name FROM schedules WHERE position = ? GROUP BY name ORDER BY count DESC";
        if ($result = $mysqli->prepare($qstring)) {

            $var = 'test';
            $result->bind_param('s', $var);

            /* execute query */
            $result->execute();

            $result =  $result->get_result();
            /* fetch value */
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                echo $row['count'] ," ", $row['name'],"<br>";
            }

            /* close statement */
            $result->close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In prepared statements, you don't put the values into the query, but instead bind them later.

In PHP, change the query to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count,name FROM schedules WHERE position = ? GROUP BY name ORDER BY count DESC";
```

Then below `if ($result = $mysqli->prepare($qstring)) {` add:

```
$result->bind_param('s', $var);
$var = 'test';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't help. printf still prints nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure if printf is the right function to use here. What is the expected output? Can you try: `echo $count;` and `echo $name;` ?

Comment: Also try adding `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);` at the top of the PHP file to see if any MySQL errors are occurring. That might help pinpoint the issue.